# Negotiated Vacation Time getting taken away

Tags: negotiation, vacation

If I negotiated 3 weeks vacation instead of 2 when I was employed.  Company gives 3 weeks after being here 10 years and it is now my 10 year anniversary, I think I should get 4 weeks, but employer is stating that I will only get 3 weeks.  Is this reasonable that I should expect the extra week?

Comment: What country are you in?  This can depend on where on this earth you are.
Has you employer gone though any changes in ownership?  I have had benefit policies change when the employer changed ownership.

Comment: What is the exact language in your offer letter or contract?

Answer (score 14):

**Unfortunately, no.**

When you negotiated the additional week of vacation, you may have intended it to mean "I get an additional week of vacation *at all seniority levels*." The hiring manager almost certainly interpreted it as "I get an additional week of vacation *until my vacation falls in line with my seniority*."

I don't think you would have too much issue if you approached your HR representative with your concerns, and non-confrontationally asked if they could authorize what you had intended originally, but at the same time, they are not obligated to oblige you.

Answer (score 10):

> Is this reasonable that I should expect the extra week?

**No, as you already got your extra week**

I think you answered yourself here:

> If I negotiated 3 weeks vacation instead of 2 when I was employed. **Company gives 3 weeks after being here 10 years and it is now my 10 year anniversary**

The thing is that you managed to get those 3 weeks *earlier* on your career. Nowhere you indicate that the company gives 4 weeks after 10 years.

I think that you are *expecting* to get an extra week after being there 10 years, but that is what they *already* gave to you since you started. Giving you 4 weeks will surely be completely different to what other coworkers get, and maybe unfair to do.

Answer (score 3):

Like so many questions on Workplace, you should expect what is in your contract, no more, no less.

You think you negotiated to get 1 week more than standard for the entire time you work there.  They think they negotiated to bump you to 3 weeks vacation earlier than other employees.  What matters is what is in the contract or employee agreement that you both signed.  If you didn't get this in writing, you probably aren't going to get anywhere.